# Assembly - Design.Extensibility, Version = 4.0.0.0

Tags: wpf, assemblies

Every time I open existing or creating a new Windows Presentation Foundation project I get this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility, Version = 4.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.'
Cannot find file.

Tried to resolve using different guides or examples. But I am totally lost...

Hope you can help me!

Thanks, Big D!

Comment: Get your machine stable again, reinstall VS.